# Block Azure App Service Request with "wp-includes" in the URL

Tags: python, azure, security

I deployed an app service in Azure and I have a set of logs from late last night with GET requests for url.com/web/wp-includes/... All of the logs resulted in a 404, but based on my reading this is a type of malicious attack. Is there a way to block these requests automatically in Azure? I do not have gateway or a VNET, but what I would like to do is set up access restrictions to block any requests with "wp-includes" in the URL for the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the Azure app request with particular url like "wp-includes" by using the rewrite tag inside the `system.webServer` tag in the `web.config` file of your Azure App Service like below and you can redirect to the error page by using the action tag in `web.config` file as shown below in the screenshot:

You can find the `web.config` file in kudu console-->**wwwroot**-->**views**-->**web.config** file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The below is the sample for rejecting the request to `/login` and you can change it as per the requirement.

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
<rule name="Block X Page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.yoursite.com" /> 
          <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/login" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.otherpage.com/" />
 </rule>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```